# Avoid repetitions to dynamize a carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I use Slider Pro plugin and I wish to dynamize my jquery code to allow me to add slide without having to add each time a new line of code, can I have some help please ?

In the code that I wrote each "item-" permit to go to a slide on mouseover but it's a little bit repetitive.

```
$(".item-0").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 0);
});
$(".item-1").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 1);
});
$(".item-2").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 2);
});
$(".item-3").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 3);
});
$(".item-4").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 4);
});
$(".item-5").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 5);
});
$(".item-6").mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel').sliderPro('gotoSlide', 6);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with for loop and also it's good practice to cache DOM element `var $carousel = $('#carousel');` if you use it more than once:

```
var itemNumber = 6; //number of items
var $carousel = $('#carousel');

for(var i = 0; i <= itemNumber; i++)
{

    $(".item-" + i).mouseover(function() {
        $carousel.sliderPro('gotoSlide', i);
    });

}
```